# Equation of constraint - Falling disc unrolling from an attached string

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, string, constrained-dynamics

Where does the equation of constraint below come from? I've tried to rationalize it, but the angle will be 0 more than one time as the string unrolls, even though y will keep going down (right?), not coming back to 0 (y=0 is considered to be at the point of suspension). I'd appreciate any help, thanks!

[image]

Comment: The angle increases continuously through $2\pi, \, 4\pi, \, 6\pi \, …$ etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The angle is $0$ only when $y=0$ at the point of suspension. It keeps on increasing thereafter, although the multiples of $2\pi$ correspond to the same point on the disc.

The equation $y = a\phi$ is just identifying the arc length as the vertical distance $y$.

Comment: Wow am I dumb! For some reason I was thinking as if it was cos or sin, where it would cyclically return to zero. It is just the angle though... Thanks for clearing my muddy mind!